# Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe

Tags: android, firebase

User gets Registered Successfully and in LoginActivity after filling User details while Authenticating it gives

> "Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe"

Error in LogCat.

**signup.java  ->  signUP_btn ClickListener**

```
  public void signingup(View view) {

    uid = findViewById(R.id.userbox);
    repwd = findViewById(R.id.repwd);
    mail = findViewById(R.id.mail);
    pwd = findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    mylayout = findViewById(R.id.signuplayout);

    String username = uid.getText().toString();
    String password = pwd.getText().toString();
    String rePassword = repwd.getText().toString();
    String email = mail.getText().toString();

    if (username.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Username!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (password.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Password!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (!password.equals(rePassword)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password should Match!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (email.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Email Id!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        try {
                            //check if successful
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                //User is successfully registered and logged in
                                //start Profile Activity here
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "registration successful",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActiviity.class));
                            }else{
                                Log.d("Error", ": "+task.getException().toString());
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Couldn't register, try again",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActiviity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView welcome,signsub,signText,reset;
    EditText user,pwd;
    Button signing;
    ImageView loginLogo;
    Animation anim,headtext,body_text,body_text2,body_text3;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activiity);

        Typeface MRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MRegular.ttf");
        Typeface MMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MMedium.ttf");
        Typeface MLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MLight.ttf");

        welcome= findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        signsub= findViewById(R.id.signsub);
        signText= findViewById(R.id.signText);
        reset= findViewById(R.id.reset);
        user= findViewById(R.id.userbox);
        pwd= findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        signing= findViewById(R.id.signBtn);
        loginLogo= findViewById(R.id.login_logo);

        welcome.setTypeface(MRegular);
        signsub.setTypeface(MLight);
        signText.setTypeface(MMedium);
        reset.setTypeface(MLight);
        user.setTypeface(MLight);
        pwd.setTypeface(MLight);
        signing.setTypeface(MMedium);

        anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.sm_tobig);
        loginLogo.startAnimation(anim);

        headtext= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.head_text);
        welcome.startAnimation(headtext);
        signsub.startAnimation(headtext);

        body_text= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.body_text);
        body_text2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.body_text2);
        body_text3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.body_text3);

        user.startAnimation(body_text);
        pwd.startAnimation(body_text2);
        signing.startAnimation(body_text3);
        reset.startAnimation(body_text3);
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActiviity.this,signup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    public void signingin(View view) {
        user = findViewById(R.id.userbox);
        pwd = findViewById(R.id.pwd);

        String Email = user.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = pwd.getText().toString().trim();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Log.d("Error", "onComplete: "+task.toString()+currentUser);
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    RecyclerView.class));

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActiviity.this, "couldn't login",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Here in LoginActivity userbox is used for email.

Comment: Hey, Did you solved this error?